# Auto-arrange multiple divs vertically in container (not as a group!)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got some `div`s in my container, which is usually taller than all these `div`s combined. I want them to be arranged evenly, but not as a group. Image below should explain what I'm trying to do. Is there any way to achieve this simple way using bootstrap 3?

[image: left: default situation, middle: goal, right: unwanted composition as a group]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* do this with pure CSS but this is actually so freakin easy with flexbox.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.child {
    flex: 1 1;
}
```

Something like that should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect usecase for **FlexBox**:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-align-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-order: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
  <div class="flex-item">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `display: felx` as your solution like this:

```css
.sides{ display:inline-block; margin: 0 10px }
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: grey;
}
#side1{ height: 100vh }
#side2{ height: 75vh }
#side3{ height: 50vh }
.box{
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0 20%;
  width: 60%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sides">
  <ul id="side1">
    <li class="box">Line 1</li>
    <li class="box">Line 2</li>
    <li class="box">Line 3</li>
    <li class="box">Line 4</li>
  </ul>
</div><div class="sides">
  <ul id="side2">
    <li class="box">Line 1</li>
    <li class="box">Line 2</li>
    <li class="box">Line 3</li>
    <li class="box">Line 4</li>
  </ul>
</div><div class="sides">
  <ul id="side3">
    <li class="box">Line 1</li>
    <li class="box">Line 2</li>
    <li class="box">Line 3</li>
    <li class="box">Line 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```